# cvcalibrateCamera2 in C

Tags: c, opencv, camera-calibration

I am learning how to calibrate camera by using openCV now.
And I have some question about how to use cvcalibrateCamera2 function that code in C, not in C++)

The question is, after find the chessboard corner,I want to derive intrinsics and distortion matrix.
There is my code:

```
  IplImage *SrcImage, *GrayImage, *NewImage;
  SrcImage = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);     // RGB
  GrayImage = cvLoadImage(argv[1],0);
  int corner_row=6; //interior number of row corners
  int corner_col=8; //interior number of column corners
  int corner_n=corner_row*corner_col;
  CvSize pattern_size=cvSize(corner_row,corner_col);
  CvPoint2D32f* corners = new CvPoint2D32f[corner_n];
  int corner_count;

  int found=cvFindChessboardCorners(
        GrayImage,
        pattern_size,
        corners,
        &corner_count,
        CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH|CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

  cvDrawChessboardCorners(
        SrcImage,
        pattern_size,
        corners,
        corner_count,
        found);

  CvMat *object_points = cvCreateMat(corner_n, 3, CV_32FC1);
  CvMat *image_points = cvCreateMat(corner_n, 2, CV_32FC1);
  CvMat *point_counts = cvCreateMat(1, 1, CV_32SC1);
  CvMat *distortion = cvCreateMat(5,1,CV_32FC1);
  CvMat *cameraMatrix = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1); 
  cvSet(point_counts,cvScalar(corner_n));

  CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix, float, 0, 0 ) = 1.0;
  CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix, float, 1, 1 ) = 1.0;

  cvCalibrateCamera2(object_points,image_points,point_counts,pattern_size,
                     cameraMatrix,distortion,NULL,NULL,0);
```

While I run it, it would make errors like this

```
For non-planar calibration rigs the initial intrinsic matrix must be specified
```

And if i replace cvcalibrateCamera2 's 9th parameter 0 by CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS, it would make

```
One of arguments' values is out of range (The intrinsic matrix must have [fx 0 cx; 0 fy cy; 0 0 1] shape)
```

I really have no idea about this, and all material in the internet is using C++, python or continuous capture photo by camera.
So that, i don't know how to adaptive to my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know, the question is pretty old, but I had the same error when using camera calibration function in javaCV.

> If CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS and/or CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO are
>   specified, some or all of fx, fy, cx, cy must be initialized before
>   calling the function.
>   [more here](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn_org/c/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera2)

And as error message said your instinct matrix has wrong form.
You have added some parameters:

```
CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix, float, 0, 0 ) = 1.0;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix, float, 1, 1 ) = 1.0;
```

These is `fx` and `fy` parameters. But you also need to add `1` to the 3rd row.
Something like this I guess:

```
CV_MAT_ELEM( *cameraMatrix, float, 2, 2 ) = 1.0;
```

In my case this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your calibration is failing since you are not giving any object or image points to your call to `cvCalibrateCamera2`.
Your matrix `object_points` should contain the calibration pattern corner coordinates, and `image_points` should contain the corresponding values in `corners`.

The first error message is probably because your matrix `object_points` is uninitialized and contains garbage. These garbage points are not on a plane, which is required by the calibration method unless you give it a guess of the intrinsics.

That said, unless you have *very* good reasons to not use the C++ interface, I would strongly suggest switching to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue in C++ and I found out that while using `cv::calibrateCamera`, The documentation mentions that if we use `cv::CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS` we need to initialize the camera matrix.
So, the solution will be

```
cv::Mat cameraMatrix = (cv:: Mat1d(3, 3)<<
        1,0,0,
        0,1,0,
        0,0,1);
    cv::Mat distCoeffs, R, T;

    cv::calibrateCamera(objp, imgpoints, cv::Size(rows, cols), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, R, T,cv::CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS);
    std::cout << cameraMatrix << std::endl;
    std::cout << distCoeffs << std::endl;
    std::cout << R << std::endl;
    std::cout << T << std::endl;
```

This situation is only for C++.
For python it's pretty simple.

```
ret, matrix, distortion, r_vecs, t_vecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], camera_matrix, None,flags=cv2.CALIB_USE_EXTRINSIC_GUESS)
    print("Intrinsic Parameter")
    print(matrix)
    print("\nRotation Matrix")
    print(r_vecs)
    print("\nTranslation Matrix")
    print(t_vecs)
```